# npm symlink error when rebuilding for homestead

Tags: node.js, npm, symlink, homestead

I am trying to use npm for a project I am working on but I am having a few problems.

When I run `npm run dev`

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code/testlaravel$ npm run dev

> @ dev /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel
> npm run development


> @ development /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

 11% building modules 9/12 modules 3 active ...ts/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now 95% emitting

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                  4:41:19 PM

 error  in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

Module build failed: Error: /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node: file too short
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at module.exports (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:19:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:18:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)

 @ ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss 4:14-266
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node: file too short
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at module.exports (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:19:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:18:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at runLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:172:11
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:32:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:182:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:275:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:157:10)
    at moduleFactory.create (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:460:10)
    at factory (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:243:5)
    at applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:94:13)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:268:11
    at NormalModuleFactory.params.normalModuleFactory.plugin (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/CompatibilityPlugin.js:52:5)
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:272:13)
    at resolver (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:69:10)
    at process.nextTick (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:196:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
                                                                                                                                                                                                           Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
/js/app.js  1.42 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app

ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-5!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Module build failed: Error: /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node: file too short
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at module.exports (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:19:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:18:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss 4:14-266
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node: file too short
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at module.exports (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:19:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:18:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at runLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:172:11
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:32:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:182:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:275:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:157:10)
    at moduleFactory.create (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:460:10)
    at factory (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:243:5)
    at applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:94:13)
    at /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:268:11
    at NormalModuleFactory.params.normalModuleFactory.plugin (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/CompatibilityPlugin.js:52:5)
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:272:13)
    at resolver (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:69:10)
    at process.nextTick (/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:196:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-02-19T16_41_20_124Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-02-19T16_41_20_181Z-debug.log
```

So I check the paths that it mentioned and they don't exist. So I looked online and saw that a suggested fix was to run `npm rebuild` but when I did I get a symlink error.

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code/testlaravel$ npm rebuild
npm ERR! path ../semver/bin/semver
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno -71
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../semver/bin/semver' -> '/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/.bin/semver'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-02-19T16_56_34_203Z-debug.log
```

I am new to npm and I don't know really know what it is. I have heard that this could be a windows problem (I am using windows) however I am not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

versions

node = v10.15.1

npm = 6.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it helps if you run command line as admin, not sure if it is necessary.
While trying to install various webpacks that npm failed to install itself I noticed that npm suggested that I run `npm audit fix` so I did. Then it install somethings and didn't give any errors. So running `npm run dev` again then started to install some additional dependencies but mentioned that I had  a package-lock.json file that needed to be deleted. So I deleted it and ran `npm rebuild` and so I tried running `npm run dev` again and it gave loads of compile errors and suggested running `npm install --save vue-resource` but I think this is because these files are the ones int the project I am working on and so it might not be necessary to run this. Then I ran `npm update` and after that I ran `composer update` because I am using homestead. Finally running `npm install` again will fix everything up.

So just to clarify

run command line as admin

`npm audit fix`

`npm run dev`

delete package-lock.json file

`npm rebuild`

`npm run dev` (it may give you guidance as to what to do next)

`npm install --save vue-resource` (in my case but could be different for you)

`npm update`

`composer update` (in my case but could be different for you)

`npm install`